# How to avoid getting contents of the same file by separate script instances?

Tags: php

Let's say we've got:
  files: a.txt, b.txt and c.txt
  script: script.php

We want to allow script to get the file's name (any of them), its contents and then delete it so that the same script that runs separately can't get the same file.

So far:

```
$scan = scandir('dir');
unset($scan[0], $scan[1]);
shuffle($scan);
$file = $scan[0];
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
if(unlink($file) !== false)
return $contents;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use file locking like [`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php).

I think the algorithm would be:

1. Open the file
2. Get the lock with `flock`
3. Check the file still exists. If it has disappeared, go to 7
4. Read the file
5. Delete it
6. Unlock it
7. Close the file, ignoring failure

Step 3 is required because any process that is waiting to get the lock from another one is bound to lose the file, as it will have been deleted by the time the lock is acquired.

I think that deleting the file when it is open is quite safe; only subsequent file operations will fail. There is nothing wrong with deleting a file that is locked because locks are not really strongly associated with files, they're simply maintained as a table of file descriptors.

I think you should close the file at the end, even though it has been deleted, as there are probably operating system resources that need to be cleaned up. I'm not sure if the close will fail or not, but you can simply ignore failure (most people ignore the return value from `close()` anyway).

Comment: This answer is a bit concise. How about some code showing how to use it?  Particularly helpful because `flock()` operates on an open file handle, while `unlink()` operates on a file name. What is the effect of deleting a file which the PHP interpreter has open?

Comment: @Jim DeLaHunt, you're right. I'm not much of a PHP programmer, so I've written an outline of how I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that wihtout actually having to delete the files would be to maintain a database table of all files you have (filenames, readstatus). Initially, they would all have readstatus set to 0. Your php script can then fetch a filename from the table and set readstatus to 1, so the same filename is not fetched again by another instance of the script.

This would take care of collisions as well, since the database would automatically implement row level or table level locking, ensuring that two instances of your script don't receive the same filename.